# Python: Read ø, æ and å in SQL select

Tags: python, sql, oracle, python-2.7, pyodbc

I've tried looking all over the internet for a solution to my problem. The thing is, I don't even have a clue how to formulate this issue correctly, since this isn't my area of expertise. Nevertheless:

I'm making a SQL call in Python. The call itself is not the issue and I've tried the same query in Toad - where it works the way it should. I'm selecting a table that contains names with the Danish character "ø". Sadly these special characters can't be read when I make the data request. Now I figured that I need to add an option to my connection that tells it to use UTF-8, so I searched a bit and found:

```
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".UTF8"
```

This works, the problem is just that the last character is removed. 
Example:

I want to read `'REFSHALEØEN HOLD'`. Without the option (above line of code) I get `'REFSHALE?EN HOLD'`, with it I get `'REFSHALE\xc3\x98EN HOL'`. Note the dropped `D` from that value.

- `Describe table` states column definition is `VARCHAR2 (16 Char)`.
- `cursor.description` returns `(COLUMNNAME, <type 'str'>, None, 16, 16, 0, False)`
- the value for the specific row is `'REFSHALE\xd8EN HOLD'`.

How do I solve this?

Has this something to do with bytes and encoding? I'm connecting to an Oracle database, in case this is important. Hope this is sufficient information.

My connection function is as follows:

```
def SQLSelect(query):
    connString  = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=" +  dbInst + ';Uid=' + schema + ';Pwd=' + passwd + ";"

    os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".UTF8"

    conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
    data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    conn.close()
return data
```

My issue is that it reads "ø, æ, å", but strings containing any of these letters are reduced by one character. **Why is this happening?**

Comment: Reopened. For what it's worth, `\xd8` is the Latin-1 codepoint for the same; if you can't find other solutions, using `value.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')` would also work. (Warning, rather than Latin-1 it could also be cp1252, that matters in a few places such as the Euro symbol).

Comment: I note that your column size is 16, and the resulting UTF-8 value is exactly 16 bytes long. I suspect that pyodbc is doing the truncating here after Oracle re-coded the value to UTF-8. Just a hypothesis, I have no real experience with Oracle and pyodbc.

Comment: and it *may* make a difference if you used a NVARCHAR2 column instead, see [Difference between VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) and NVARCHAR2(10)](//stackoverflow.com/q/4508351)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated. Can I build the decode and encode onto my connection? Figured I could use it on a single value, can I use it on arrays as well?

Comment: I'm not an expert with these kinds of issues myself, but some other things to investigate: What if it's not pyodbc but rather pandas which is doing the truncating? For example, what if you do the same query directly with pyodbc? What if you use cx_Oracle instead? And if the value in the database isn't UTF-8, how about trying to [set `os.environ["NLS_LANG"]` to the actual encoding in the database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)? That last one actually makes the most intuitive (but possibly naive!) sense to me.

Comment: OK, after doing a little reading of the [NLS_LANG FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) (specifically the myths section), it would appear you're supposed to use this to tell Oracle your *client's* (i.e. local) encoding, not to tell your client the database's encoding. But this doesn't change the fact that what you *want to receive* is Latin-1 or Windows-1252, and not UTF-8.

Comment: @JohnY: Oracle re-codes the data from the database codec to your client codec. That is working correctly. What is not working is getting 16 codepoints; 16 *bytes* are delivered, which means truncated data here.

Comment: @JohnY: I've tried a lot of different settings. None of them seem to work

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I completely agree about the 16 bytes, but since the client's codec is adjustable (via Python), and since the value in the column fits into 16 bytes *in the database*, it seems to me the smoothest (if not the only) way forward would be to tell Oracle to send us the data in the same encoding it's already using; that way there shouldn't be any issues about unexpected expansion of the data. Once we have (all!) the data safely in our hands, we can convert to whatever encoding we like. And it doesn't sound like OP even really wants UTF-8 specifically. They just want all the data.

Comment: @JohnY: I wrote `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS` from the link you added. **NLS_LANGUAGE** is `DANISH`, **NLS_TERRITORY** is `DENMARK` and **NLS_CHARACTERSET** is `WE8MSWIN1252` this should result in `os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "DANISH_DENMARK.WE8MSWIN1252"`. Sadly this doesn't change a thing. I've tried it with `AMERICAN_AMERICA` as well and the ***NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET*** (`AL16UTF16`). Nothing works

Comment: When you tried using `WE8MSWIN1252` as your character set, what did you get back? The question mark in place of the Danish character, but no truncation?

Comment: Exactly, I got `REFSHALE\xd8EN HOLD`

Comment: OK. If that's really what you got, then you had what you needed all along, and the issue is not that the database or pyodbc is giving you the wrong data; it's that whatever you are using to *view* the data can't handle the Danish character and is *displaying* a question mark in place of the data, and there are no actual question marks in what you've received. The way you described your situation, it sounded like specifying UTF-8 for the NLS_LANG was giving you 15 *correct* characters, and you were trying to figure out how to get that 16th character. But that's not it at all, is it?

Comment: The issue is that I can't display the Danish character - that's correct. The IDE (Spyder 3) I use has no problem displaying "ø", when I print it just like that, however it somehow cannot decipher the latin1 code (as far as I understand it). I still think the issue lies within my pyodbc connection function, since the query itself works fine in VBA. Works fine means it displays all 16 characters as well as the Danish letter.

Comment: @JohnY: Never mind - the above would be the case as well, if you are right and I think you are. Somehow the latin1 code is not deciphered. The question is, how do I solve that?

Comment: First of all, it's not Latin-1, it's Windows-1252. That was what you found out by querying `V$NLS_PARAMETERS`. How to solve your problem depends almost entirely on what exactly you are using to view the data, and why it's important that you see the intended glyph. The answer might be "fiddle with a font setting on your app"; or "use a different app to view the data"; or "don't worry about it - it's a cosmetic issue and is irrelevant to your actual task". But you haven't yet given that information, and in any case it's far adrift of the posted question. I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @JohnY: Thank you - this was a work-related issue, thus the late response. As you said, the issue is aesthetical only. I wanted to use the strings for new SQL queries and thought, since ‘ø’ isn’t displayed properly, the query will not Work (won't include the 'ø'). But that was a false assumption – should’ve tested that right away, would have saved all of us a lot of time. Nevertheless do I thank you for your responses and valuable time!